# Make checkbox clickable outside label

Tags: html, css, checkbox, css-position

I have a checkbox with pseudo div class inside a label. I have to position checkbox(div) with negative right property, which makes the checkbox to be outside label and unclickable. Is there any way to make the checkbox clickable without changing html?

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + div::before {
     right:-35px !important;
      left:auto !important; }

    input[type="checkbox"] + div::after {
     left:auto !important;
      right:-33px !important;
       width:auto; }
```

```html
<label>
     <span>text</span>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
       <div></div>
    </label>
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, where you want to click?

Comment: Sorry, edited question. I need to click on checkbox

Comment: can you update the HTML like this and see `<label>
     <span>text</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
       <div></div>`

Comment: I asked if it is possible without changing html. Otherwise I wouldn't have the problem :(

Comment: Oops my bad...are you using jquery or any JS

Comment: Not for this particular piece. I think I should ask my question in a different way, but thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("text").setAttribute('onclick','doThis(event)');

document.getElementById("label").setAttribute('onclick','doThat()');

function doThis(event){
event.preventDefault()
}

function doThat(){
 alert('normal label click');
}
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + div::before {
     right:-35px !important;
      left:auto !important; }

    input[type="checkbox"] + div::after {
     left:auto !important;
      right:-33px !important;
       width:auto; }
```

```html
<label>
     <span id="text">text</span>
      <input type="checkbox"/>
       <div></div>
    </label>
```

You can achieve the same via JavaScript by overriding the element click behavior and tweaking to your way.